# Android Widget Visibility strategy

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a situation I am struggling to solve.

I have in my layout 2 widget. One ImageView and one ProgressBar (Indeterminate).

I want to show the progressbar until my ImageView image load.

The problem is ImageView fill all the area and Progressbar has a specific size. When I set the progressbar visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE, the progressbar doesn't appear anymore but her size still fill some area which makes Imageview not fill all area.

How to set progressbar invisible and put ImageView on top ?

Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bck_card_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_medal"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/card_progressbar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/lunch_per_kilo"
            android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:paddingStart="116dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_xlarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/valid_until"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_flash"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/like_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_heart_24dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_regular" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use FrameLayout which contain inside your ImageView and ProgressBar.

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/card_progressbar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now you can hide and show ProgressBar.

Comment: My main ViewGroup is a FrameLayout, but inside it I have a LinearLayout, where my progressbar is inside.

Comment: could u post your xml?

Comment: sure, I edited my question and have included the layout